# Operator increased by funcation and trying to make a request from it

Tags: javascript

I can't understand something at Javascript, Im trying to increase a ball size,it works well but every increased ball number I need to make a clickable ball example(Ball increased to 1, ball1 is working and others not).

```
var isBall1On = true;
  var isBall2On = false;

function onBall5Click() {
    var ball5 = document.querySelector(".ball5");
    var ball1 = document.querySelector(".ball1");
    var ball2 = document.querySelector(".ball2");
    var isBall1On = ball1;
    var isBall2On = ball2;
    ball5.innerText = Ball5increase;
    Ball5increase = Ball5increase + 1;
    // Increased by number postive + 1
    if (Ball5increase > 3) {
      Ball5increase = 1;
    }
    if (Ball5increase == 1) {
      var ball2 = false;
      console.log(typeof ball2);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code, and what isn't working as you expected? Also, where is `Ball5increase` declared? And you are redeclaring `ball2` for nothing at the end of the function, and the following line might as well be `console.log("boolean")`.

Comment: I declared Ball5Increase as Ball5Increase = 1; at global. What I'm expect is that Ball5 are number 1 means that Ball1 is working and ball2 isn't.

Comment: Still trying to fix it and I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.